# Command for reloading file from disk to show changes when using “less?”

Tags: command-line, unix, less

In `less` is there a command for reloading a file from disk, so that less will show any changes made to a file since less was started? This would saving me have to terminate and restart `less` if I want to see changes to the file I'm viewing.

Comment: If appended is enough see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196168/does-less-have-a-feature-like-tail-follow-name-f

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4351/is-there-a-way-to-dynamically-refresh-the-less-command

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two possibly relevant commands detailed in the fine manual for `less(1)`

```
   R      Repaint the screen, discarding any buffered  input.   Useful  if
          the file is changing while it is being viewed.

   F      Scroll  forward, and keep trying to read when the end of file is
          reached.  Normally this command would be used  when  already  at
          the  end of the file.  It is a way to monitor the tail of a file
          which is growing while it is being  viewed.   (The  behavior  is
          similar to the "tail -f" command.)
```

Answer (score 5):

`R` for repaint does not always reload the file.<sup>[1]</sup>

A workaround that always reloads the file is to press `hq`, which will open the Help page, then quit. It has a side effect of forcing the file to reload.

---

[1] Here are some examples of situations that `R` do and do not reload:

- `>` and `>>` changes: DO get reloaded
- `sed -i`, gEdit, TextEdit: DO NOT get reloaded
- On Linux, `vi` changes: DO get reloaded
- On Mac, `vi` changes: DO NOT get reloaded

I believe the difference comes down to whether the inode changes (you can check with `ls -i foo.txt`). If the inode changes, then `R` will not work.

Comment: works for me on Mac. `less --version` gives `less 487 (POSIX regular expressions)`

Comment: @johnsullivan Thanks for the comment. I revisited my answer and found that it depends on the situation. When using `vi` to edit on Mac, `R` doesn't work. But `vi` on Linux does. See my revised answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I worked around this problem using a shell script that auto-reloads `less` on exit:

```
while true; do less -K file.txt || exit; done
```

With this script, I can hit `q` to reload the file, and `CTRL+C` to exit back to the bash shell. The `CTRL+C` behavior is enabled via the **`-K`** option. Your last search term will be preserved.

This can be further refactored by using the colon (`:`) to create an empty expression, via `do :` ...

```
while less -K file.txt; do : ; done
```

#### Drawbacks

The current viewing position will always be rest to line 0.

#### Practical Example using `mintty`

In my windows (GitBash) environment I set up a script that opens a new terminal window (mintty) for less-viewing a file:

```
lesswin() { mintty bash -c "while less -K \"$@\"; do : ; done;" & }
```